# Some of the form submit buttons don't work and some do

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have multiple buttons on the same form and some of them work and some don't. This is the form with auto-submit inputs:

```
 <form id="mainForm" asp-controller="Packages" asp-route-systemTypeIndex="@Model.FilterByPackageTypeChoice" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
      <lablel style ="color:red" onclick="openPackageUploadForm()">+ New Package</lablel>
      <label style="padding-left:5%">Sort by:</label>
      <select id="SortBy" class="border-0" asp-for="@Model.PackageSortBy" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<PackageSortBy>()" onchange="this.form.submit()"></select>
      <label style="padding-left:5%">Order:</label>
      <select id="SortOrder" class="border-0" asp-for="@Model.PackageSortOrder" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<SortDirection>()" onchange="this.form.submit()"></select>
 </form>
```

These are the submit buttons that work:

```
<button type="submit" class="form_upload-edit_button" form="mainForm" asp-action="CreatePackage" asp-route-page="@Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage" asp-route-systemTypeIndex="@Model.FilterByPackageTypeChoice">ACCEPT</button>
<button type="submit" class="form_upload-edit_button" form="mainForm" asp-action="UpdatePackage" asp-route-page="@Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage" asp-route-systemTypeIndex="@Model.FilterByPackageTypeChoice">ACCEPT</button>
```

And these are the two that DON'T WORK:

```
<button type="submit" class="packages_edit_delete_bar_button" form="mainForm" asp-action="SelectPackagesForUpdate" asp-route-page="@Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage" asp-route-systemTypeIndex="@Model.FilterByPackageTypeChoice">EDIT</button>
<button type="submit" class="packages_edit_delete_bar_button" form="mainForm" asp-action="DeletePackage" asp-route-page="@Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage" asp-route-systemTypeIndex="@Model.FilterByPackageTypeChoice">DELETE</button>
```

I also trying with giving different names to the buttons, but still was the same. I guess I am missing some basic concept here.

Comment: what does `DON'T WORK` mean? When you click the submit button, it doesn't send request to action or show an error? I don't find any differret between thses buttons except target action, Are your sure the `SelectPackagesForUpdate` and `DeletePackage` receive get request?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `method` attribute to your form.

Make all of the actions POST with the `[HttpPost]` attribute in the controller.

Now add the `method="post"` in the form tag like so.

```
<form id="mainForm" asp-controller="Packages" asp-route-systemTypeIndex="@Model.FilterByPackageTypeChoice" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
</form>
```

You should also check the **Network** tab in the browser inspect to see if the request is even being sent to the controller.

And while you are there, you should also check the console to see if there are any errors.

If this doesn't work I would recommend to use ajax for the job.

Comment: @mesashvili_Irakli yes, the request is being sent to the controller because if I put those buttons in separate form, then they work. The form in my case must stay of type get

Comment: Yes but if the button is for deleting something, type get is not the way to go

Comment: If I were you I would use ajax calls for all of those calls, It would more readable and better for the application it self.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp 
Check the docs, It is very easy to use